# Error from server bundle generated using Webpack: Could not find package.json up from: /

Tags: webpack

I need to bundle my Node.js server side code with the `node_modules` to generate `server.js`. I am able to generate the bundle but when I run the server, it throws an error `Error: Could not find package.json up from: /`

My directory structure:

```
package.json
webpack.config.js
node_modules/
server/
  - index.js
  - apiCallbacks/
     - logger.js
```

After debugging, I noticed that this may be because `webpack` is not able to resolve the node module require’d in `logger.js`. The node modules require’d in `index.js` do not have any issues.  If I do not require `logger.js` in `index.js`, the server is up and running.

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './server/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'server.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server'),
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      },
    ],
  },

  target: 'node',
};
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Have you any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @ramiromd: nothing yet :(

Comment: I hadthe same problem this morning. In my case, the problem was an external node package (pretty-logger). Try unload all external packages and load one by one.

Comment: @ramiromd external as in outside of your project directory?

Comment: No, packages installed with npm. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ramiromd In my case, all packages are (obviously) installed using npm inside of my project root directory. Outside of this project root directory, there is no node_modules directory in any of its parent directory.